# How to collect data from HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, css, database, forms

I want to create a company website that has an employment section in the section will have a form to collect data from the employees requesting for jobs. how do i execute and where will the data by stored?

Comment: Maybe this can halp: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3249522/13183434

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
        <input type="text" id="txtName" placeholder="Enter your name" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="txtAge" placeholder="Enter your age" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="txtEmail" placeholder="Enter your email address" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <select id="selCountry">
            <option selected value="">-- Choose the country --</option>
            <option value="India">India</option>
            <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
            <option value="USA">USA</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <textarea id="msg" name="msg" placeholder="Write some message ..." style="height:100px"></textarea>
    </div>

    <!--Add to button to save the data.-->
    <div>
        <input type="button" id="bt" value="Save data to file" onclick="saveFile()" />
    </div>
</div>
```

let saveFile = () => {

```
    // Get the data from each element on the form.
    const name = document.getElementById('txtName');
    const age = document.getElementById('txtAge');
    const email = document.getElementById('txtEmail');
    const country = document.getElementById('selCountry');
    const msg = document.getElementById('msg');
    
    // This variable stores all the data.
    let data = 
        '\r Name: ' + name.value + ' \r\n ' + 
        'Age: ' +age.value + ' \r\n ' + 
        'Email: ' + email.value + ' \r\n ' + 
        'Country: ' + country.value + ' \r\n ' + 
        'Message: ' + msg.value;
    
    // Convert the text to BLOB.
    const textToBLOB = new Blob([data], { type: 'text/plain' });
    const sFileName = 'formData.txt';      // The file to save the data.

    let newLink = document.createElement("a");
    newLink.download = sFileName;

    if (window.webkitURL != null) {
        newLink.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(textToBLOB);
    }
    else {
        newLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textToBLOB);
        newLink.style.display = "none";
        document.body.appendChild(newLink);
    }

    newLink.click(); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you but i dont know JavaScript to this level!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).